# Is there anyway to annotate only required fields for JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm working on to convert Hibernate objects to XML using JAXB. In our classes, we've around 50 fields from which I would need only 10 of them.

Basically, I'd defined XmlType#propOrder with 2 properties. JAXB complained that some public getters are not part of proporder. 
I see that if I don't mark a property with either of XmlTransient/XmlElement, JAXB complains about it. Is there any way to skip writing 'XmlTransient' on every field?

Comment: Search/replace using a regex or copy/paste 40 times? It doesn't really seem that daunting.

Comment: Ofcourse, this is doable. But still exploring better alternatives :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` so that only the annotated fields/properties are marshalled to XML.  JAXB does not require any annotations.  Annotations are only required to override the default behaviour.  What exceptions are you seeing?

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Basically, I'd defined XmlType#propOrder with 2 properties. JAXB complained that some public getters are not part of proporder.

Comment: @Prabhjot - A JAXB implementation will expect that all properties mapped to XML elements will be included in the propOrder on `@XmlType`.  Setting `@XmlAccessorType` should give you exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Blaise : I have JPA Entity (annotated) with two fields (A and B, both JAXB annotated also). For some usecase I can populate only A and for some only B. When I serialize entity, it always try to serialize both (which is obvious) and lazy-loads the dependencies - THIS lazy loading I want to avoid (certainly, I can not use @XmlTransient). I want to customize this default behavior for different usecases. Thanks in advance